# How to combine all "paragraphs" into one line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
This is some text
and there are line breaks.
but this is still a paragraph.

And now we have another paragraph.
What will you do about it?
```

I am having trouble with the Find/Replace to convert the blocks of text that are separated by a blank line into one line, like this:

```
This is some text and there are line breaks. but this is still a paragraph.

And now we have another paragraph. What will you do about it?
```

It seems like the regex should have a forward-looking parameter, but I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\r\n]\K\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with:   # a single space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\r\n]         # any character that is not a linebreak
\K              # forget it
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!\R)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a linebreak after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Fine work, sir. Thank you. It's interesting to note that it doesn't work if you manually "Fine Next / Replace". You need to click "Replace All"

Comment: @pbarney: You're welcome, glad it helps.  As said in my answer, you have to click on  `Replace all`. It's because you have more than 1 match to be replaced.

Comment: Oh yes, I saw that you specified it, I just think it's interesting that there's a case where "find next" doesn't work the same. Because I typically use "find next" to test my regex search, this knowledge could help me when I'm not seeing the results I expected.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work more or less:

- Find `\r\n(\r\n)?`
- Replace with  `\1\1`
- The `\1` refers to what is matched by the (optional) capturing group `(\r\n)?`:

  - For a single line break, this is nothing, so only a space will be added.
  - For a double line break, this is the second line break and it's doubled.

Final result:

[image]

Each paragraph gets an extra space at the end, which might not be desirable. They're easy to get rid of by another Find & Replace round: find  `\r\n` and replace by `\r\n`.